# use of unresolved identifier 'entityDescription'

Tags: swift, core-data

An error **use of unresolved identifier 'entityDescription'** is coming in my code. Even after a lot of failed attempts am unable to resolve it.

```
   import UIKit
import CoreData

class SwiftCoreDataHelper: NSObject {

class func directoryForDatabaseFilename()->NSString{
    return NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/Library/Private Documents")
}


class func databaseFilename()->NSString{
    return "database.sqlite";
}


class func managedObjectContext()->NSManagedObjectContext{


    do { try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(SwiftCoreDataHelper.directoryForDatabaseFilename() as String, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil) }
    catch {
        print("Error Creating Directory for DB")
    }
    //        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(SwiftCoreDataHelper.directoryForDatabaseFilename(), withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error)

    let path:NSString = "\(SwiftCoreDataHelper.directoryForDatabaseFilename()) + \(SwiftCoreDataHelper.databaseFilename())"

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String)

    let managedModel:NSManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil)!

    let storeCoordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedModel)

    do {
   try storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        }

    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)

    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator

    return managedObjectContext


}

class func insertManagedObject(className:NSString, managedObjectConect:NSManagedObjectContext)->AnyObject{

    let managedObject:NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectConect) as NSManagedObject

    return managedObject

}

class func saveManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->Bool{
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}


class func fetchEntities(className:NSString, withPredicate predicate:NSPredicate?, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->NSArray{
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()


    guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) else {
        //handle error here
        return 
    }

    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
    if let predicate = predicate {
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    }

    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
  var items = NSArray()
   do { items = try managedObjectContext .executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
   } catch {
       print("Fetch Request Failed")
   }
    return items}}
```

The error is coming in the code-

```
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
     if (predicate != nil){
       fetchRequest.predicate = predicate!
   }
```

I am not understanding where am going wrong.
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: On a side note: that `nil` check and force unwrap (`!`) would be better as just: `if let predicate = predicate { fetchRequest.predicate = predicate }`

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov when i use your solution it shows **value of type 'NSFetchRequest' has no member 'predicate'**

Comment: nope, it is not resolving still

Comment: @user6718553 That error would've existed before, too

Comment: @eric thanks a lot for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `if let` statement, the new variable name is bound only for the duration of the `if let` scope. You can't use it afterwards. What you're after is the `guard` statement:

```
guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) else {
    //handle error here
    return
}

fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
if let predicate = predicate {
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
}
```

Comment: In the return statement an error pops up which says **non-void function should return a value"**

Comment: `guard` statements require you to exist the scope by using `return`/`throw`/`break`/`continue`/etc. I put that in there as a placeholder, given the limited information i have to work with. You'll have to put in an appropriate value yourself

Comment: @user6718553 You're having some really basic problems with Swift. You should probably check out [Apple's free Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0), which would have answered both of your questions easily.

Comment: @Tom i have just started learning ios app development..i will surely refer to that, thanks a lot

Comment: @user6718553 If you feel this answer has resolved your question, please rate it and mark it as accepted

Comment: @alexander i did upvote the answer but it says that votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but they do not change the publicly displayed score. And i have posted the entire code could you please suggest me what can i put the appropriate value with return? i am trying lot of values but everything is going in vain

Comment: @user6718553 Oh wow, why do you put type annotations on every constant/variable lol

Comment: @alexander hehe i have just started learning and i am finding it too tough.

Comment: @user6718553 Hold on, I'll help clean this up

Comment: @alexander thank you so much you are a life saver:))

Comment: @user6718553 I'm just going through this now. Look at line 25: you make a `String` literal, but assign it to an `NSString`. On the next line, you use `as` to turn it back into a `String`, like the one you started with. You can just say `let path = "..."`

Comment: @alexander oh yes i didn't notice that..Thanks i will change that

Comment: @user6718553 So in the function `fetchEntities(className:withPredicate:managedObjectContext:)`, what do you think is an appropriate course of action to take if `NSEntityDescription.entityForName(_:)` is `nil`? Throw an error? `fatalError()`? Return `nil`? Return an empty array?

Comment: @alexander umm see basically am developing an application in which you put the name and contact details of a person regarding a particular task. Would returning nil be okay? Or on throwing an error it says something like it cant be empty would that look more better?

Comment: @user6718553 I think `nil` would be appropriate

Comment: @alexander ok, so in the guard statement should i return nil?

Comment: @user6718553 [Let's continue our discussion here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120985/discussion-with-user6718553)

Comment: @alexander it says i need 20 reputation to talk on chat. Can i contact you through your personal mail or something?

Comment: @alexander it is not letting me type in the chat

Comment: @user6718553 Hmm that's annoying. http://www.disposablechat.com/chat/user6718553?password=